# One-to-many relationship with "default" child instance

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys

(I'm having a bit of a brain-fart and I can't remember the name of this problem-class, because I've seen solutions to this before on SO, so please mark this as a duplicate of another question if you find a better answer on here from before).

Imagine we have a database of Cars and CarOwners. Each CarOwner has many Cars (one-to-many) but each CarOwner also has a favourite Car.

Here's an initial schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Owners (
    OwnerId bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name    nvarchar(100)
)

CREATE TABLE Cars (
    CarId   bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Vin     varchar(17),
    OwnerId bigint,

    FOREIGN KEY (OwnerId) REFERENCES Owners(OwnerId)
)
```

For an owner to have a favourite car, the `Owners` table needs to be extended with a new column `FaveCarId bigint` with a foreign-key constraint to the `Cars` table, but adds an unncessary coupling between Owners and Cars (e.g. if we added `Houses` or `Computers` to the database, when we get information about the Owner we don't care what their `FaveCar` is. This also adds a chicken-and-the-egg problem where the `FaveCar` column must be `NULL`able in order to create a `Owner` row, add their new `Car` row, then add the new `CarID` back to the `FaveCar` column.

...so another solution is to extend the `Cars` column to add a boolean `IsFavourite` column, but this has a problem in that nothing's stopping someone from giving two `Car`s (that belong to the same `Owner`) a set `IsFavourite` column value. A unique constraint (between `OwnerId+IsFavourite` won't help either because if an Owner has 3 or more cars, 2 of them will have `IsFavourite=0`.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a database inheritance schema.

Answer (score 2):

**Association Table Solution**

```
CREATE TABLE OwnersFavoriteCar (
    OwnerId bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    CarId bigint,
    FOREIGN KEY (OwnerId) REFERENCES Owners(OwnerId),
    FOREIGN KEY (CarId) REFERENCES Cars(CarId)
);
```

You could create an association table, normally used for `M:N` relationships, but set the primary key to `OwnerId`. This prevents the owner from having more than one favorite car.

If you think that you may add a `House` or `Computer`, and that the owner will also have a favorite of either in addition to the `Car`, you either rename it to `OwnersFavoriteStuff` and add two columns:

```
HouseId bigint -- with FK constraint
ComputerId bigint -- with FK constraint
```

---

**Database Inheritance solution**

Or, you could go for database inheritance:

```
CREATE TABLE Things (
    ThingId bigint PRIMARY KEY
    ThingType nvarchar(10) CHECK (ThingType in ('car', 'house')) -- type discriminator
);

CREATE TABLE Cars (
    ThingId bigInt PRIMARY KEY,
    Vin     nvarchar(17),
    OwnerId bigint,
    FOREIGN KEY (OwnerId) REFERENCES Owners(OwnerId),
    FOREIGN KEY (ThingId) REFERENCES Things(ThingId)
);


CREATE TABLE Houses (
    ThingId bigInt PRIMARY KEY,
    Color   nvarchar(17),
    Rooms bigint,
    OwnerId bigint,
    FOREIGN KEY (OwnerId) REFERENCES Owners(OwnerId),
    FOREIGN KEY (ThingId) REFERENCES Things(ThingId)
);

CREATE TABLE OwnersFavoriteThing (
    OwnerId bigint ,
    ThingId bigint,
    Type nvarchar(10) CHECK (Type in ('Car', 'House')), -- Used to discriminate amoung different Things
    PRIMARY KEY (OwnerId, ThingId), -- Makes sure that owner cannot have more than one favorite thing of each type
    FOREIGN KEY (OwnerId) REFERENCES Owners(OwnerId),
    FOREIGN KEY (ThingId) REFERENCES Things(ThingId)
);
```

With this database inhereitence schema, `Things` is the top level, and `Cars` and `Houses` both extend `Things`.

You would typically use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on `Cars` and `Houses` that would first insert a row into `Things`, get the new ThingId, and insert that into the `Cars` or `Houses`.

Now, your FavoriteThing table remains in third normal form, regardless of how many new tables you create in your database. The `type` column is used to discriminate between different types of `things`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following data model:

[image]

IsFavorite is an attribute of an OwnedCar and is identified by **both** Person and Car, not solely by Person or Car.
So a **composite key** is required.
You can implement IsFavorite as a column of OwnedCar, or create a new entity FavoriteCar to add integrity.

To constrain OwnedCar and FavoriteCar, you need to create **unique indexes** (alternate keys).

- For OwnedCar, add a unique index for CarId, so that each Car can be owned by only one Person.
- For FavoriteCar, add a unique index for OwnerId, so that each Person has only one favorite car.

---

The problem without a composite key is that, you can insert a favorite car whose owner **does not own** the car.

```
CREATE TABLE OwnersFavoriteCar (
    OwnerId bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    CarId bigint,
    FOREIGN KEY (OwnerId) REFERENCES Owners(OwnerId),
    FOREIGN KEY (CarId) REFERENCES Cars(CarId)
);
```